# Traversing XML structure in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

How can I read the state in this object of an array

I am getting this result when I

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

display_output($xml->country[0]);
```

RESULT:

```
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   '@attributes' => 
   array (
    'name' => 'Afghanistan',
),
'state' => 
array (
0 => 'Badakhshan',
1 => 'Badghis',
2 => 'Baghlan',
3 => 'Balkh',
4 => 'Bamian',
5 => 'Farah',
6 => 'Faryab',
7 => 'Ghazni',
8 => 'Ghowr',
9 => 'Helmand',
10 => 'Herat',
11 => 'Jowzjan',
12 => 'Kabol',
13 => 'Kandahar',
14 => 'Kapisa',
15 => 'Konar',
16 => 'Kondoz',
17 => 'Laghman',
18 => 'Lowgar',
19 => 'Nangarhar',
20 => 'Nimruz',
21 => 'Oruzgan',
22 => 'Paktia',
23 => 'Paktika',
24 => 'Parvan',
25 => 'Samangan',
26 => 'Sar-e Pol',
27 => 'Takhar',
28 => 'Vardak',
29 => 'Zabol',
),
))
```

I would like to get the state, how can I do it? I have tried, unfortunately it is not working.

```
$a = $xml->country[0]->state[0];
```

*below is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<countries>
 <country name="Afghanistan">
    <state>Badakhshan</state>
    <state>Badghis</state>
    <state>Baghlan</state>
    <state>Balkh</state>
    <state>Zabol</state>
  </country>
</countries>
```

*Update, found the answer*:

```
            $xml   = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

            $country = array();
            $state = array();

            for($x=0;$x<count($xml);$x++)
            {
                $country[] = (string)$xml->country[$x]->attributes()->name;
                if(isset($xml->country[$x]->state))
                {
                    for($y=0;$y<count($xml->country[$x]->state);$y++)
                    {
                        $state[$x][] = (string)$xml->country[$x]->state[$y];
                    }
                }
            }

            return array($country,$state);
```

Comment: could you also post the value of `$xml_string`?

Comment: Got the answer. sorry

$xml->country[0]->state

Comment: if that worked, sure man no prob

Comment: @Ponce The answer in your comment above is fragile.  What happens if XML element order changes?

Comment: actually I have for loop for the XML. I just made it shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you would use xpath to look for the attribute "Afghanistan" on a country element, since you know this is the country you are looking to get data for.

```
$afghanistan = $xml->xpath("//country[@name='Afghanistan']");
$afghan_states = $afghanistan->state;
$first_state = $afghan_states[0];
```

Or if you don't need the country level information, you could use a more specific xpath selector:

```
$afghan_states = $xml->xpath("//country[@name='Afghanistan']/state");
$first_state = $afghan_states[0];
```

This would make your code work even if there were changes in country element ordering in the XML.